# While loop isn't detecting first line of text file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that loads text files to populate two separate list boxes in the form. It's supposed to read every line, and add each line to a single listbox. The first line of the text file is being ignored for some reason, and I'm not sure why.

This is what each line of the text file is:

- cd Armor 1 True+
- bg Tool 2 False+
- o Weapon 3 False-
- xz Consumable 1 True-

I believe my while loop is the issue, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with it. I need the program to loop through more than one line. When I ran the code without using a loop, the first line of the text file was added to the appropriate list box with no issues.

The code below is attached to the load button within my form.

```
        private void loadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openTextFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openTextFile.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt) | *.txt";

        string listItemString;
        string[] listItem;

        if (openTextFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (StreamReader openStream = new StreamReader(openTextFile.OpenFile()))
            {
                listItemString = openStream.ReadLine();
                listItem = listItemString.Split(' ');

                while ((listItemString = openStream.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (listItemString.EndsWith("+"))
                    {
                        listItemString = listItemString.Replace("+", "");
                        cart.Items.Add(listItemString);
                    }
                    else if (listItemString.EndsWith("-"))
                    {
                        listItemString = listItemString.Replace("-", "");
                        delivery.Items.Add(listItemString);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading first line before while loop in the line of code `listItemString = openStream.ReadLine();`. Then you are overridden this value in the first loop iteration when calls `while ((listItemString = openStream.ReadLine()) != null)` first time.

Just delete 2 lines of code befoer yout loop:

```
listItemString = openStream.ReadLine();
listItem = listItemString.Split(' ');
```